# How to regenerate product thumbs programatically?

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, thumbnail

I know there is a way to delete image cache:

```
protected function cleanImageCache()
{
    try {
        echo "Cleaning image cache... ";
        flush();
        echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_image')->clearCache();
        echo "[OK]" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die("[ERROR:" . $e->getMessage() . "]" . PHP_EOL);
    }
}
```

How to I **regenerate** the images after that?

*I know that by browsing the site they get generated but before that happens (e.g. if some of them have not been browsed yet) Google Image bot gets 404 from the server which I want to avoid.*

Answer (score 2):

you will need to load the instance per product

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product()->getId()); // pass product id here 

echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(50,50);
```

**OR**

```
(string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail')->resize(200);
```

**Get store config value**

The values you can get in `Mage::getStoreConfig('abc/xyz/hfc')` are saved in `core_config_data` table of magento database.

Before this function can return anything, there has to be an entry in path column of `core_config_data` table. There is a column for `store_id` as well in `core_config_data`. If no store id is passed as an argument, default `store id 0`, which belongs to admin

instead of each you can store it some variable for google feed.

just checkout for this first 1 or 2 product then apply for whole `.xml`

**Fetch Product collection**

```
 public function getCollection() {

        $store = Mage::app()->getDefaultStoreView();
        $rootCategoryId = $store->getRootCategoryId();
        // Gets the current store's id
        $this->_storeId = $store->getStoreId();

        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addStoreFilter($this->_storeId)                               
                        ->addAttributeToFilter(
                                'status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
                        )->addUrlRewrite($rootCategoryId);


        // added to check in stock item
        Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);

        $collection->setPageSize(250);

        return $collection;
    }
```

call above function and loop

```
 $collection = $this->getCollection();
 foreach ($collection as $product) { 

       $products[$i]["Id"] = $product->getId();
       $products[$i]["Sku"] = $product->getSku(); // end so on.
 }
```

hope this will work for you.

Comment: The code you provide is too specific, e.g. what if the size needs to be read from config instead of being hard-coded? Could you please provide a solution compatible with the function above, so we can make it full-featured for the purpose?

Comment: @george you can use my updated anser

Comment: Sorry but this 'abc/xyz...' and the other explanatons are unclear to me (I am not a Magento developer). If you know how it should be done, please write the whole function. Can you do that please?

Comment: here is detail example extension https://inchoo.net/magento/create-configuration-for-your-magento-extension/

Comment: That is unrelated. The example by Inchoo is for creating a config for extension. My question is how to regenerate store thumbnails.

Comment: @george, i have given to use store config values for your thumbnail size. you can post another question if you have to be more clear about how store config is working. :)

Comment: if my answer is little helpful to u pls don't forget to acpt so someone can use if for future reference.

Comment: the question is how to regenerate **all** the thumb images, not just for a single product id. I just don't know how to automatically loop through all products. So if you do - please provide a version of the function above which rebuilds all thumbs. Then I would be glad to mark your reply as a helpful answer.

Comment: @george, my answer is updated with fetch product collection. i hope now you have enough understanding to get your answer. ;)

Comment: Thanks. This looks much better. Unfortunately it is still incomplete as there is no info how to get image sizes for image, small_image and thumbnail without having to use fixed numbers (and so make a potential mistake). Also it seems to me this will work only for the default store. I guess a complete solution would do `foreach ($stores as $store)` instead. But I understand this is an arduous task perhaps and perhaps I am going to leave this problem as it seems difficult to get a full answer. Anyway if you are willing to complete it I will mark it as an answer. But I upvote it for sure. 10x

Comment: @george you misunderstand the purpose of this site. It's not to find someone to do everything for you. You need to put in some effort yourself!
You admit you're not a Magento developer and yet you're asking how to do something programmatically. That would be fine if you are trying to _become_ a Magento developer. Otherwise, either find an extension that does what you want, or hire a developer. Don't expect the community to give you a free ride.